# What is a single word I can use to describe a non-query SQL statement?

Tags: naming, dbms

I'm trying to come up with a good name for a data access object that executes non-query SQL statements.  I know DML is a valid term, but I wanted to make sure it is the best.

Right now we have OracleNonQuery, but I'm hoping to find something better.

**UPDATE:** OracleDML or OracleDMLStatement are good suggestions.  I'll probably go with one of those unless someone has a better term.

Comment: Can you show us what one of these statements looks like? I would have thought that DML and DDL would have covered most of it.

Comment: DAO? ........10

Comment: DML and DDL covers all of it.  I'm just looking for name suggestions that imply a statement that isn't a query.

Comment: @j0rd4n: can you give an example of one these statements that's not a query? If you do, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - A simple insert statement.  It uses SQL but it isn't a query.

Comment: @j0rd4n: DML usually is considered to include Insert, Update, Delete because they all Modify/Manipulate Data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call it a statement. Then you can have an enumeration of statement types: `OracleDMLStatement`, `OracleDDLStatement`, and just `OracleStatement`. If it's an actual piece of PL/SQL you could have `OraclePLSQLStatement`, but without an example, it's hard to suggest much else.

Comment: +1 this term is used in the book *SQL Antipatterns* as well.

Comment: I need to modify my question.  I shouldn't have mentioned DDL because we aren't allowing those.  OracleDMLStatement works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> DML and DDL covers all of it. I'm just looking for name suggestions that imply a statement that isn't a query.

I wouldn't conflate DML and DDL into "Statement" or some other single term.

I'd keep things separate and call non-query DML "DML".

There are three sublanguages of SQL that have separate purposes and conflation is a potential issue.

No end-user-oriented application should execute DDL (or DCL) for that matter.

It should be doing DML Statements only.  And non-query DML is -- well -- still DML.

Other admin applications may do DDL or even DCL.  Because that's so very separate, I'd stay away from "Statement" and use DDL or DCL.

I think the tree looks like this.

- DML insert, update, delete

  - Query, i.e., the SELECT statement, a subclass of DML.
- DDL create, drop
- DCL grant, revoke

Comment: You are correct.  I should have not have said DDL because we aren't allowing those.  DML is all we are doing.  I'll modify my question to exclude DDL.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a DAO to access an oracle database.  You are creating a DAO that accesses an Oracle database to solve a problem.  Describe the probelem in the name of the DAO.  For example, you might create a TpsReportReaderDAO to read TPS reports.  Another example is, FlammyJammyHootyDAO might be used to apply Flammy Jammy to Hooty.

Summary: Use meaningful names; Oracle is the tool not the purpose.  I don't use a Metal headed, wood handled tool to drive nails, I use a Hammer.

Comment: Actually, the goal is to create a generic DOA that wraps a nice OOP pattern we are using.  This object abstract the database plumbing and will be used by our data tier.